# Reason for xml irrational output format

Tags: xml

This is really driving me nuts. I can think of no reason for this. I have run out of ideas on why it is doing this, I'm hoping someone can give me a reason for this. The problem is this: I have an xml file I am modifying to de-identify patient information. One line in the xml is causing me headaches and I can't figure out why. The original line in the file is:

```
<id root="2.16.840.1.999999.3.109.3.2722.4.1.1.999999.2.9" extension="1999552"/>
```

When I modify the line and write it out the

```
<id extension="123456" 
 root="2.16.840.1.999999.3.109.3.2722.4.1.1.999999.2.9"
```

I only modify the extension value. I have a similar line for a telecom value and it gets written out correctly: From:

```
<telecom use="WP" value="tel:1(917)999-0899"/>
```

TO:

```
<telecom use="WP" value="tel:1(800)999-9999"/>
```

I took out the code that modifies the extension value, added in just modifying the root value, but it still writes it out swapped. I tried two different ways, one using the same code I did for telecom, didn't work, and then tried another approach, which also did not work.
At this point I'm stumped. I am probably staring at the reason, but I can't see it. If anyone can look at this and give me an idea as to why this is happening only on this line I would really appreciate it.

Used same code that already works, changing the tag and attribute values to match what I needed, also tried a new code approach with the exact same results. Searched for an answer in forums to no avail.
Here is a snippet from the xml file:

```
<recordTarget>
    <patientRole>
      <id root="2.16.840.1.999999.3.109.3.2722.4.1.1.999999.2.9" extension="1999552"/>
      <addr>
        <streetAddressLine>999 E 11th St</streetAddressLine>
        <city>Galena</city>
        <state>CO</state>
        <postalCode>81099</postalCode>
        <country>US</country>
      </addr>
      <telecom use="WP" value="tel:1(917)999-0899"/>
      <telecom use="MC" value="tel:1(917)999-0899"/>
      <patient>

#this approach does not work for the id root/extension
for mrn in doc.getElementsByTagName("id"):
 mrnID = mrn.getAttribute("extension")
 mrn.setAttribute("extension", "123456")

#Also Tried this approach and it didn't work as well
#Just tried writing out ONLY the id root value to see if that made
#a difference. It didn't values where still swapped even though I never
#operated on the extension attibute
if doc.getElementsByTagName("patientRole"):   
  for mrn in doc.getElementsByTagName("id"):
   rootID = mrn.getAttribute("root")
   oidID = rootID 
   mrn.setAttribute("root", oidID)

#telecom section this works for the telecom values
 for telecom in doc.getElementsByTagName("telecom"):
  phone = telecom.getAttribute("value")
  if phone[0:4] in ["mail"]:
   telecom.setAttribute("value", "mailto:anon@anon.com")
  if phone[0:3] in ["tel"]: 
   telecom.setAttribute("value", whichPhone)

#AT the end, this is how I write out the file
#outFile = "mod-" + inputName + ".xml"
 os.chdir(anonymizedDir)
 f = open(outFile, "w")
 f.write(xml_pretty_str)
 f.close()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code you have. Also add the tag of the programming language you are using to the question. Provide a [mcve], which can be tested by other. It should show the error you have, but describe it in detail what the exact error is.

Comment: Since the time I posted this question, I found out I was really chasing my tail. It turns out my code is not swapping the elements, tags, attributes.......it is in the writing out of the file. I removed all code that modifies that element, the <id root="2.16........and it turns out, it is written out in a swapped condition. This:

Comment: This: <id root="2.16.840.1.999999.3.109.3.2722.4.1.1.999999.2.9" extension="1999552"/> Turns into this: <id extension="199952" root="2.16.840.1.999999.3.109.3.2722.4.1.1.999999.2.9"

Comment: This is the only line in the entire xml file 
that this happens on and I am puzzled as to why. The sequence I use is    f = open(outFile, "w")   f.write(xml_pretty_str)   f.close()   Is there another way to write out an xml file?

Comment: I'm going close this question and open up another now that I know what the issue is. I've tried another solution, let me just clarify what the issue I'm running into in another string.